Clear Firefox cache and cookies automatically
To clear the Firefox's cache one must do: Menu - Settings - Privacy & Security - Cookies and Site Data - Clear Data - Cookies and Site Data/Cached Web Content - Clear now. But one must do this manually.
Is there any setting that would bring Firefox to clear its own cache the same way but automatically over a certain period of time? Some setting in about:config may be?

There's an option to clear all when Firefox shuts down. Isn't that a viable option for you? If not, why? Please [edit] the question accordingly.
